# Ionic 3 error install native plugin after Ionic 4 release

Tags: ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

I get a problem using native plugin ionic 3 when install Native Store is  success, but when I try to add in app module, the text editor show a red line and when I try to run I found an error like below. Here I install Native-store (https://ionicframework.com/docs/v3/native/native-storage/)

Red line in text editor, successful install but when add in app module show red line.
[image]

[image]

This is error in console when run 'ionic cordova run android'.

```
[14:40:05]  ionic-app-scripts 3.1.8
[14:40:05]  build dev started ...
[14:40:05]  clean started ...
[14:40:05]  clean finished in 71 ms
[14:40:05]  copy started ...
[14:40:07]  deeplinks started ...
[14:40:08]  deeplinks finished in 1.04 s
[14:40:08]  transpile started ...
[14:40:27]  typescript: D:/myProject/ionic/myApp/src/app/app.module.ts, line: 57
            Argument of type '{ declarations: (typeof VerificationPage | typeof LoginPage | typeof PrivacyRegisterPage |
            typeof...' is not assignable to parameter of type 'NgModule'. Types of property 'providers' are
            incompatible. Type '(typeof SplashScreen | typeof FCM | typeof InAppBrowser | typeof AppVersion | typeof
            Market | typ...' is not assignable to type 'Provider[]'. Type 'typeof SplashScreen | typeof FCM | typeof
            InAppBrowser | typeof AppVersion | typeof Market | type...' is not assignable to type 'Provider'. Type
            'NativeStorageOriginal' is not assignable to type 'Provider'. Type 'NativeStorageOriginal' is not assignable
            to type 'ClassProvider'. Property 'provide' is missing in type 'NativeStorageOriginal'.                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
[14:40:27]  ionic-app-script task: "build"
[14:40:27]  Error: Failed to transpile program
Error: Failed to transpile program
    at new BuildError (D:\myProject\ionic\myApp\node_modules\@ionic\app-scripts\dist\util\errors.js:16:28)
    at D:\myProject\ionic\myApp\node_modules\@ionic\app-scripts\dist\transpile.js:159:20
    at Promise (<anonymous>)
    at transpileWorker (D:\myProject\ionic\myApp\node_modules\@ionic\app-scripts\dist\transpile.js:107:12)
    at Object.transpile (D:\myProject\ionic\myApp\node_modules\@ionic\app-scripts\dist\transpile.js:64:12)
    at D:\myProject\ionic\myApp\node_modules\@ionic\app-scripts\dist\build.js:109:82
    at <anonymous>
[ERROR] Command not found: ionic-app-scripts
```

Please help me to solve this problem.

Thanks.

Comment: You have to use `import { DocumentViewer} from "@ionic-native/document-viewer/ngx";` like this.

Comment: No, What do you install DocumentViewer for ?, I try to install NativeStorage, not DocumentViewer. Do you have another idea/solution ? @MustafaLokhandwala

Comment: at last you have a problem to import the module in `app.module.ts` right?

Comment: ya, right, I try to import in another ionic 3 project the result is same, error. One day before I install its ok, but after ionic 4 release to be error. @MustafaLokhandwala

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try To Find .. Second Last Previous Version of Plugin & Append While Adding Plugin

```
npm install @ionic-native/native-storage@4.19.0
```

Here... Latest Version is 5.0.0 So Add @4.19.0 Please Don't Make Assumption Based On
Number Go In Repo or npm link try to find our previous version then append.

Then do your All Step Regularly.

Thanks

Comment: This is the solution.
It made me mad, 'cause it's about 2 hours I try to install any pulgin unsuccessfully.

Comment: @Krunal Vaghela, Do you know where can I check the lastest version. . ?lika a list of version

Comment: You Can Check in npm.. tell me For Which Plugin You Are Trying ?

Answer (score 13):

All your `@ionic-native` modules now need `/ngx` at the end for Angular projects. Just fix it like this:

```js
import { NativeStorage } from '@ionic-native/native-storage/ngx';
```

Apply this to every `@ionic-native` plugin/module.

Answer (score 0):

Goto  https://www.npmjs.com.

Search for the ionic-native package that you want to install.

In your case, its 'ionic-native-storage'.
Check the versions and choose the one which was released before the Ionic 4 Beta release and then install the appropriate version using the same command.

```
ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-nativestorage@"====add your version here===="
```

After that the plugin will work the same way as it did.
No need to fiddle with adding 'ngx' at the end of the path.

Answer (score -1):

For those that end here running on Ionic 5 just fix your import statement from:

> import { BarcodeScanner } from ‘@ionic-native/barcode-scanner’;

to:

> import { BarcodeScanner } from ‘@ionic-native/barcode-scanner/ngx’;

Otherwise the above work for Ionic 3.9x and Ionic 4.xx